# regex to prevent double hyphens/apostrophes

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a rule that ensures that hyphens and apostrophes in string must be preceded and followed by a letter (a-z)(unless it's a first or last character).so it should disallow `--,'',-','-` what I have now is just a quick fix. Here is what I am using:

```
if(fName.match(/--+/)||fName.match(/''+/)||fName.match(/-'+/)||fName.match(/'-+/)){
   $('#em1').html('improper use of hyphens and/or apostrophes');
}
```

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading right, you want to disallow `-'`, `--`, `'-`, and `''`. E.g. you want to disallow any `-` or `'` followed by any other `-` or `'`. If so:

```
if (fname.match(/[-']{2,}/)) {
    // Disallow
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to make sure that a double minus is preceded by a letter.